# how to accept multiple connection to the device

Tags: php, sockets, stream

I am creating a socket script that will listen to our 3 devices.and the device is setup in one server ip and one port only.

```
 $file = fopen('txt.log','a+');
    $server = stream_socket_server('tcp://'.$ipserver.':'.$port, $errno, $errorMessage);

    if(!$server) {
        echo "$errorMessage ($errno)<br />\n";
    }
    else{

        while($client = @stream_socket_accept($server,$timeout)) {
               stream_copy_to_stream($client, $file);
               fclose($file);
               fclose($client);


        }

    }
```

but the problem is that if one device is connected,the two devices cannot connect anymore.I appreciate some one can help me how to get this work.or give me some idea

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/

Comment: thank you for the link,but i am confuse what should i do so that my two or more devices can connect

Comment: I put stream_set_blocking($client,1); inside my while loop but i thinks it's not working

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = fopen('txt.log', 'a+');
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://$ipserver:$port", $errno, $errorMessage);
if (!$server)
    echo "$errorMessage ($errno)<br />\n";
else
{
    $s = array($server);
    $t = $timeout == -1 ? NULL : $timeout;
    while ($r = $s and stream_select($r, $n=NULL, $n=NULL, $t))
        foreach ($r as $stream)
            if ($stream == $server) // new client
                $s[] = stream_socket_accept($server, -1);
            else
                if (!fputs($file, fgets($stream)))
                {
                    fclose($stream);
                    array_splice($s, array_search($stream, $s), 1);
                }
}
```